# OrbitControls: Set default camera zoom

Tags: three.js

I'm using the OrbitControls script on my site. By default it is zoomed a little too far in.

I was wondering what the best way to manually set, or set the default camera zoom is?

Answer (score 0):

Set the camera position to a comfortable distance before creating the OrbitControls:

```
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 1, 0.1, 1000)
    camera.position.z = -10

    // Now initialize camera controls
    const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
    controls.rotateSpeed = 2.0
    controls.zoomSpeed = 5
    controls.panSpeed = 2
    controls.enableZoom = true
    // ...
```